# Accessing an ArrayList within an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have made an ArrayList (members) of ArrayLists (memberFriends). So, "member" has a list of friends.

This method receives the name of a member, and its goal is to list all of the members' friends. I am confused how to access the ArrayList of friends from within the member list.

```
public java.lang.String[] getPals(java.lang.String name) {

    if(members.contains(name)) {
        memberFriends.get(members.indexOf(name));
        String[] friends = memberFriends.toArray(new String[memberFriends.size()]);
    }
    return friends;

}
```

So basically, what I want to do here is, say the friends' name is Joe, I want to go to Joe in the ArrayList members and turn the ArrayList of his friends into an array. I am just confused on how to access Joe's friends. What I tried to do above in my third line of code was access the name "Joe." Now I'm confused how to access Joey's ArrayList of friends.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case for Generics. If you wish to access `memberFriends.get(0)` (which will print an array), then need to indicate memberFriends like this:

```
List<List<String>> memberFriends = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Not sure if I understood: you can then try iterating:

```
for (List<String> member : memberFriends) {

  for (String s : member) {

   
  }
}
```

Comment: at the top of my class I have

Comment: private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> memberFriends = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Comment: but what I want to do in this method is take one of these members, and make an array of their friends

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have control over how to represent members and their friends, this is how I would recommend doing it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

    public static class Member {
        String name;

        public Member(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Member [name=" + name + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Member, ArrayList<Member>> members = new HashMap<>();
        populateMembers(members);
        System.out.println(members);
        getPals(members, "Ross");
    }

    private static Member[] getPals(Map<Member, ArrayList<Member>> members, String name) {
        if (members.get(name) != null) {
            return members.get(name).toArray(new Member[members.get(name).size()]);
        } else {
            return new Member[] {};
        }
    }

    private static void populateMembers(Map<Member, ArrayList<Member>> members) {
        String[] names = new String[] { "Joe", "David", "Ross", "Monica", "James" };
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<Member> friends = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = i+1; j < names.length; j++) {
                friends.add(new Member(names[j]));
            }
            members.put(new Member(names[i]), friends);
        }
    }
}
```

Option two (if you insist on using two array lists, members and memberFriends:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

    public static class Member {
        String name;

        public Member(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Member other = (Member) obj;
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Member [name=" + name + "]";
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Member>> memberFriends = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        populateMembers();
        System.out.println(members);
        System.out.println(memberFriends);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getPals("Ross")));
    }

    private static Member[] getPals(String name) {
        int index = members.lastIndexOf(new Member(name));
        if (index != -1) {
            return memberFriends.get(index).toArray(new Member[memberFriends.get(index).size()]);
        } else {
            return new Member[] {};
        }
    }

    private static void populateMembers() {
        String[] names = new String[] { "Joe", "David", "Ross", "Monica", "James" };
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<Member> friends = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
                friends.add(new Member(names[j]));
            }
            members.add(new Member(names[i]));
            memberFriends.add(friends);
        }
    }
}
```